# Using a Raspberry Pi to create Usb-to-multiple 3.5mm converter?

Tags: python, audio, input, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm excited. I'm a long-time lurker here at SO, but I've never posted. Here goes!

I'm trying to develop a device that would connect to a host RPi through (preferably) USB, and would have multiple 3.5mm jack outputs. The goal, ultimately, is to get the device to use a standalone program that, when a button is pressed (keyboard, or other external input), a specific sound (or set of sounds) would go through a single 3.5mm output. Now, I understand that there's going to (most likely) have to be an external box, and I also realize that I'm in above my head, but I'm trying to create this as more of a hobby and as a learning experience.

Basically, the way it would go is that the user would set which inputs triggered which outputs beforehand on the custom software in the RPi. The input would then trigger that ouput then await a new signal. I figure I'm going to need to also build a physical box to house the amount of 3.5mm jacks I want (i figured 3-5.)

So, where do I need to start? I don't need a guide on how to do this, more of a step in the right direction. From what I can discern, there's not anything out there that does this. If there is, please show me and I'll get that instead. I've done a lot of googling on this, and I'm thinking that I'll use Raspbian on the Rpi, and code the software using Python. I know I'll also need to build a driver so that the external box and the RPi can communicate. Lastly, I assume that I'll need some type of circuitry for the external box. That's where it gets hairy to me. I've never dealt in physical I/O except for a bit of modding. Where would I start my search there?

Any help at all is appreciated, and thanks for reading this huge post. Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: There is another site for [Raspberry pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com)

Comment: There are also off the shelf sound adapters for usb.

Comment: And additionally, depending on how many outputs you want to have you could just use the GPIO pins of the rpi.

Comment: thanks for pointing me the right way!